# mongo $or/$and with two selectors for geo query

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to query my mongo for two geospatial queries. Do I need to send the request twice - maybe I am doing the $or wrong? Either way here is the lowdown -

The user types in a location and I can eitehr have it send back data from "bandLocation" or "bandTour" - each are geospatial queries. Here is the request that works but only does one of the selectors at a time.

```
    router.get('/allbands/:lng/:lat',   (req, res) => {
    quoteGenerator.find(
        {
        "bandLocation.geometry":
            { $near :
                {
                $geometry: { 
                    type: "Point",  
                    coordinates: [parseFloat(req.params.lng), parseFloat(req.params.lat)] 
                },
                $maxDistance: 160934,
            }
            }
        },
        )
.then(
                function(bands){
                    res.send(bands)
                }
            )
        });
```

I tried to use the $or and the $and operator but it doesnt send anything back. Here is my code so far with the $or operator

```
    router.get('/allbands/:lng/:lat',   (req, res) => {
    quoteGenerator.find(
        {
            $or : [
                {
                    "bandLocation.geometry":
                    { $near :
                        {
                        $geometry: { 
                            type: "Point",  
                            coordinates: [parseFloat(req.params.lng), parseFloat(req.params.lat)] 
                        },
                        $maxDistance: 160934,
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bandTour.geometry":
                    { $near :
                        {
                        $geometry: { 
                            type: "Point",  
                            coordinates: [parseFloat(req.params.lng), parseFloat(req.params.lat)] 
                        },
                        $maxDistance: 160934,
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
.then(
                function(bands){
                    res.send(bands)
                }
            )
        });
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. You may consider putting together  a complete reproducible test case with data.